# Is it possible to compare and match fields within referenced documents in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, deployment, aggregation-framework

## I am trying implement Dynamic Searching in MongoDB with Referenced Documents

> #### Market Schema:

```js
const MarketSchema = new mongoose.schema({          
    marketName: String,          
    // ... rest of the fields  
});
```

> #### Moderator Schema:

```js
const ModeratorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    username: String,
    // ... rest of the fields
});
```

Now the Document that I trying to work on

> #### ModeratorToMarketMapping Schema:

```js
const ModeratorToMarketMappingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    moderatorId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
    },
    marketId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Market",
    },
    // ... rest of the fields
});
```

I want to either filter the data based on `marketName` of the market or based on `name or username` of the moderator using ModeratorToMarketMapping documents.

I want the result to something similar to that what the following queries will produce

if search by market

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Users AS u
JOIN ModeratorToMarketMapping AS map ON  u.id = map.moderatorId 
JOIN Market AS m ON map.marketId = m.id
WHERE m.marketName LIKE '%${FILTER_VALUE}%'
```

if search by name/username

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Users AS u 
JOIN ModeratorToMarketMapping AS map ON  u.id = map.moderatorId 
JOIN Market AS m ON map.marketId = m.id
WHERE u.name LIKE '%${FILTER_VALUE}%' OR u.username LIKE '%${FILTER_VALUE}%'
```

I have thought of two approaches

#### 1] Less efficient one but it works

In this solution If I want to filter by market, then I first search the 'markets' from `Market Collection` and then get the `id's of moderator` from the `Mapping schema` and then populate the data accordingly, similarly if I want to search by name or username then I fetch the `moderators` first the then get the `id's of markets` from `Mapping schema` and then populate the data

Now It's evident that this is `not` a good approach and will definitely fail when the data to search through grows.

#### 2] Looks efficient but partially works

so I searched for 2nd approach and I ended up with this but this doesn't work as I want it to work.

the code for the same is as follows

```js
    const { criteriaKey, filterValue } = req.query;

    let query = {};

    if (criteriaKey && filterValue) {
        const regex = new RegExp(filterValue, "i");

        if (criteriaKey === "market") {
            query = { "market.marketName": { $regex: regex } };
        } else if (criteriaKey === "name") {
            query = {
                $or: [
                    { "moderator.name": { $regex: regex } },
                    { "moderator.username": { $regex: regex } },
                ],
            };
        }
    }

    const moderators = await ModeratorMarketMapping.aggregate([
        {
            $match: query,
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "markets",
                localField: "marketId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "market",
            },
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "moderatorId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "moderator",
            },
        },
        {
            $unwind: { path: "$market", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true },
        },
        {
            $unwind: { path: "$moderator", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true },
        },
    ]);
```

How to make the about code work or is there another better way to do this except switching to RDBMS

Comment: That schema looks nicely normalized with a join table, i.e. perfect design for a relational database.  If you are set on using that schema, RDBMS would be the obvious choice.

Comment: @Joe I completely agree with you, but the project is built using mongodb and changing database would be hassle, so i was looking for a mongodb solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have designed your schema does scream relational data and you have tackled it with an aggregation. That is probably the right approach for your current schemas if you can get it working but mongodb is designed for flexibility. Denormalisation in your case could be an optimal approach.

You could store a reference to each other like so:

**Market Schema**:

```js
const MarketSchema = new mongoose.schema({          
    marketName: String,
    moderatorId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
    },          
    // ... rest of the fields  
});
```

**Moderator/User Schema**:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    username: String,
    marketId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Market",
    },
    // ... rest of the fields
});
```

Then when your query comes in decide which Model to use for the query and `populate` the references like so:

```js
const { criteriaKey, filterValue } = req.query;

if (criteriaKey && filterValue) {
    if (criteriaKey === "market") {
        const docs = await Market.find({ 
            marketName: { 
                $regex: filterValue, $options: 'i' 
            } 
        }).populate('moderatorId');
    } else if (criteriaKey === "name"){
        const docs = await User.find({
            $or: [
                { name: { $regex: filterValue, $options: 'i' } },
                { username: { $regex: filterValue, $options: 'i' } },
            ]
        }).populate('marketId');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome. If you found the answer useful please consider [marking as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.). @Aditya

Comment: Yeah sure! I'm new and still learning... I appreciate your help and i will mark it as accepted when i get time